# .NET Identity Token invalid, machine key the same

Tags: asp.net

I am having a problem where I generate a token to put in an email for a user to reset their password.  I am running .net 4.5 sites on IIS 7 on two web servers behind a load balancer.

The token works great as long as it is used on the same server it was generated from.  But if the other server is the one that gets hit, then an "Invalid token." error is generated.

I have three urls I can test from.  The load balanced url, and urls directly to each server behind the load balancer.  I can generate a token from the load balanced url and verify which server I hit, then I can use that token on the direct url for the same server.  But no combination of using it on the opposing server works.

Initially my machine key was not the same on both machines, and I fixed that issue over a month ago.  But it has not solved the issue.  Both servers are using the same code base.  And the fact that the load balanced domain name token works on the domain name that goes directly to the server behind it means that the domain name itself is not a factor as near as I can tell.

What else could be wrong with my configuration?

Comment: No one has any ideas? That is disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the .net Identity system cannot handle web farms by default using it's UserTokenProvider.  So far the only way I have found around this issue is to write your own UserTokenProvider.  Fortunately, it turns out this is very easy to do and requires very little code.

You probably already have a UserManager implementation that looks similar to this:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager() : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyApp");
        this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create(".Net Identity"));
    }

}
```

Alter it to looks like this.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager() : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        var provider = new MachineKeyProtectionProvider();
        this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create(".Net Identity"))
        {
            TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
        };
    }

}
```

And then create the missing classes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper for the custom @MachineKeyDataProtector class
/// </summary>
public class MachineKeyProtectionProvider : IDataProtectionProvider
{
    public IDataProtector Create(params string[] purposes)
    {
        return new MachineKeyDataProtector(purposes);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Custom key provider because Microsoft's default provider does not support web farms
/// </summary>
public class MachineKeyDataProtector : IDataProtector
{
    private readonly string[] _purposes;

    public MachineKeyDataProtector(string[] purposes)
    {
        _purposes = purposes;
    }

    public byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Protect(userData, _purposes);
    }

    public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, _purposes);
    }
}
```