# Alternative to DpapiDataProtectionProvider in ASP.NET Identity which does not use Machine Key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, reset-password

I am looking for an alternative to DpapiDataProtectionProvider because this uses machine key and a user requests to reset the password from other application rather than the main MVC product, the token is always invalid.

I have got an ASP.net MVC application and an API application. They are both using the same token provider  passwords like this:

```
var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyWeb");
        appManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("MyWebToken"));
```

DpapiDataProtectionProvider relies on machine key, so the token is invalid when using a link from an email. What alternative could I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problems, I ended up using MachineKeyProtectionProvider like this solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356571/net-identity-token-invalid-machine-key-the-same) and I included this line in the startUp:

```
app.SetDataProtectionProvider(new MachineKeyProtectionProvider());
```

and I added machine key in web.config files.